TypeScript Interface that uses matching on the property (key)
I am looking to do something unusual I guess. I have the following code:
import { writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

interface VariablesType {
  myVar: string;
  [key: string]: string | number;
}

export class Variables {
  static async load(): Promise<VariablesType> {
    return (await import('variables.json')).default;
  }

  static save(variables: VariablesType): void {
    const prettyJson = JSON.stringify(variables, null, 2);
    writeFileSync(
      `${path.join(__dirname, `variables.json`)}`,
      prettyJson,
    );
  }
}

In my code I need to be able to do something like:
const variables = await Variables.load();

variables[`myVar${someStringDeterminedAtRuntime}`] = 'some string';


Is there some way that I can account for that in the interface? For example (knowing this is completely wrong):
interface VariablesType {
  /myVar.*/: string;
  [key: string]: string | number;
}

The reason I want this is so that when I do the dynamic import, I want myVar<whatever> to be assigned the correct type of string.
I admit that I'm probably approaching this from the wrong angle and that perhaps there's a better way of doing this. Any help would be most appreciated.

Presumably you're looking for a pattern template literal index signature as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz I looked at the documentation link and thought "I've seen that and it's not exactly what I'm looking for" and then I looked at your playground link and it's exactly what I was looking for - the docs could do with having a similar example to add clarity! tldr; thank you! And please add your comment as an answer that I can accept.

There are no regular-expression-validated string types in TypeScript. So /myVar.*/ can't be directly expressed that way. There's an open feature request for such types at microsoft/TypeScript#41160, for what it's worth.
Luckily, the particular pattern of a string that starts with a specified prefix, can be represented using template literal types with a string placeholder, as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#40598:
type StartsWithMyVar = `myVar${string}`;
let str: StartsWithMyVar;
str = "myVarHello" // okay
str = "myVarGoodbye" // okay
str = "Greetings" // error!

Additionally, you can use placeholder template literal types as keys in index signatures:
interface VariablesType {
  [key: StartsWithMyVar]: string;
  [key: string]: string | number;
}

So VariablesType means that every property with a string valued key must be of type string | number, and in particular, every property that starts with "myVar" must be of type string:
const variables: VariablesType = {};
variables.myVarHello = "x"; // okay
variables.myVarGoodbye = 123; // error
variables.Greetings = 123; // okay

Now your code example compiles as written:
function foo(someStringDeterminedAtRuntime: string) {
  variables[`myVar${someStringDeterminedAtRuntime}`] = 'some string';
}

Playground link to code
